# ActionScript 3 movieclip with interchangeable images

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, flashdevelop

I'm creating a game using Flash Develop and ActionScript 3.0 and I can't figure out how to make a "Character Creation" menu, in the sense that, I want to animate a movieclip full of images (head, torso, arms, etc.) and then change out any image with another.
So I'd like players to be able to choose what kind of sunglasses they want their character to have, for example, and the different sunglasses will keep the animation that I made with the original ones.

From what I know so far I can export a movie clip as a .swf and use it as such, but how do I change out images and keep the animation?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how much actionscript you know.. but if you just want an idea how to do it and not the whole thing in code...

I would personally make different movie clips for the different parts of the body that can be changed and then change frames in that move clip. For example one movie clip with different hairstyles, one with (sun)glasses and so on.. and then just go to then next frame in the "hairMC" to change the hairstyle.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean!  So the whole person movie clip is made of say 4 different movie clips (Hair,Head,Body,Arms) which remember their own animation positions, and if the Hair movie clip contains 4 frames each containing different styles, then I can just call a gotoandStop()?

I am a proficient programmer, but I am just starting out in ActionScript, so I can handle complicated code too.  For now I don't have Flash, I'm just using Flash Develop, is there any way to work with/make movie clips in Flash Develop alone?

Comment: Exactly :) This seems to me like the smartest and easiest way to do it.

Comment: I have never used Flash Develop, so I don't know about that.. sry

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is to create MovieClips that all implement the same [Interface](http://www.developria.com/2009/10/interfaces-and-dynamic-class-i.html) and then have other MC's higher up that know how to use the particular Interface. For example, if you had an `IArm`, it might know how to swing and how to grasp (and it might grasp by using an `IHand`). A fat `ITorso` might attach the arms at a different spot than a thin one.

And your `Character` might have an `IHead`, `ITorso`, etc. When you created a Character, you could either pass in these components via the constructor (I'm not a big fan of constructor arguments for Views, but it's one way to do this), or you can expose setters on your Character that allow you to set these properties one at a time.

This gives you tremendous flexibility in how to put your character together--none of the pieces know precisely how the others are put together, but the methods they need to operate on are in place, so you can put in any implementation you can think of.

Comment: Hmm, I am more interested in how to interchange the actual images rather than how to implement the code.  The key to my problem is to keep an animation but to use different images.  But thank you for your reply.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think what I suggested wouldn't work for that. I use that sort of approach for similar tasks all the time.

Comment: It's my ignorance with AS3 that is probably keeping me from using your suggestion Amy.  I was specifically looking at how to change images, whereas your method is what I could use after I figure out how to change them.  I'm really new to AS3.  Your solution dealt with getting the images to work together, not how to have the same pointer point to a different image.  Thank you very much for your reply its just not exactly what I needed to know :)

Comment: The image would be a MovieClip with a Base Class that implemented the Interface